# An unusual Python syntax element frequently used in Matplotlib

Tags: python, syntax, reference, matplotlib

One proviso: The syntax element at the heart of my Question is in the Python language; however, this element appears frequently in the Matplotlib library, which is the only context i have seen it. So whether it's a general Python syntax question or a library-specific one, i am not sure. What i do know is that i could not find anything on point--either in the *Python Language Reference* or in the Matplotlib docs.

Those who use and/or develop with the excellent Python plotting library, Matplotlib will recognize the syntax pattern below. (

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as MPL

>>> l, = MPL.plot(s, t)      # s & t are ordinary NumPy 1D arrays
```

***What is the construction on the left-hand side of this expression?*** And,

***what is the purpose for using it?***

I am familiar with Python's ***assignment unpacking***, e.g.,

```
>>> a, b = [100, 200]
```

I'm also aware that in Python one-item *tuples* are sometimes represented as t,

And either could be the answer to the first question above; if so then i don't yet understand the reason why only the first element of the value returned from the call to *plot* is needed here.

(note: "l" is a lower case "ell"; i am using this letter because ls is the letter most often used here, probably because it is bound to an object that begins with the same letter-see below).

---

Some additional context:

The call to *plot* returns **a list of *line2D* instances**:

```
>>> type(l)
  <class 'matplotlib.lines.Line2D'>
```

*So l is an object of type line2D.*

Once bound to the lines2D object, this "variable" is usually seen in Matplotlib code like so:

```
>>> l.set_color("orange")
```

This expression changes the color of the line that represents the data values inside the plot window (the "plot line")

Below is one more example; it shows a common scenario for this "variable-comma" construction, which is embedding small toolkit/graphics-backend-independent widgets in a Matplotlib plot window, e.g., to toggle on/off by checkbox, multiple data series appearing in the plot window.

In the code below, a simple Matplotlib plot and a simple widget comprised of two checkboxes one for each data series are created.

***l0*** and ***l1*** are again bound to calls to *plot*; both appear a couple of liens later when their get_visible and set_visible methods are called within a custom function passed in when *on_click* is called.

```
from matplotlib.widgets import CheckButtons

ax = plt.subplot(111)
l0, = ax.plot(s, t, visible=False, lw=2)
l1, = ax.plot(t, s1, lw=2)

rax = plt.axes( [.05, .4, .1, .15] )
check = CheckButtons(rax, ('raw', 'transformed'), (False, True))

def fnx(checkbox_label):
    if checkbox_label == 'raw': 
        l0.set_visible(not l0.get_visible())
    elif checkbox_label == 'transformed': 
        l1.set_visible(not l1.get_visible())

check.on_clicked(fnx)

plt.show()
```

Comment: To give a bit of a reason as to why `plot` returns a sequence, `plot` is modeled off of matlab's plot, so it accepts an arbitrary number of lines to plot with a single function call.  (e.g. you can do things like `plt.plot(x, 1*x, x, 2*x, x, 3*x, x, 4*x)` and plot 4 lines, or pass in 2d arrays and get a line for each row)  Because of this, `plot` always returns a sequence, even if there's only one line.  It's actually fairly rare to plot more than one line at a time with `plot`, so you very often see `l, = plt.plot(x, y)`.

Comment: `frequently used in Matplotlib` could you link to an example in the docs?

Comment: such as http://matplotlib.org/users/legend_guide.html#controlling-the-legend-entries

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
l, = v
```

Is [almost] the same as

```
[l] = v
```

Example

```
>>> l=[3]
>>> [v] = l
>>> v
3
>>>
```

Answer (score 17):

It's [**sequence unpacking**](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#tuples-and-sequences) for a single element.

```
>>> l = [3]
>>> v, = l
>>> v
3
```

Answer (score 0):

Some explanations:

we know

```py
a, b = 1, 2
```

gives `a == 1, b == 2`

**in my opinion**, if python found the left side is a "tuple", it would unpack the right side.

```py
a, = [1]
```

python may think it as `(a,) = [1]`

then try to unpack it, so we get `a == 1`