# line, = plot(x,sin(x)) what does comma stand for?

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I'm trying to make an animated plot. Here is an example code:

```
from pylab import *
import time

ion()

tstart = time.time()               # for profiling
x = arange(0,2*pi,0.01)            # x-array
line, = plot(x,sin(x))
for i in arange(1,200):
    line.set_ydata(sin(x+i/10.0))  # update the data
    draw()                         # redraw the canvas

print 'FPS:' , 200/(time.time()-tstart)
```

I don't understand the `line,`. Without comma, the code doesn't work.

Comment: possible duplicate of [An unusual Python syntax element frequently used in Matplotlib](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9731779/an-unusual-python-syntax-element-frequently-used-in-matplotlib)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The comma is Python syntax that denotes either a single-element tuple. E.g.,

```
>>> tuple([1])
(1,)
```

In this case, it is used for argument unpacking: `plot` returns a single-element list, which is unpacked into `line`:

```
>>> x, y = [1, 2]
>>> x
1
>>> y
2
>>> z, = [3]
>>> z
3
```

An alternative, perhaps more readable way of doing this is to use list-like syntax:

```
>>> [z] = [4]
>>> z
4
```

though the `z, =` is more common in Python code.

Comment: Just outsped me, +1, but I disagree that a more readable way of doing this is using list-like syntax, I would use this instead: `line = plot(x, sin(x))[0]`.

Comment: Or even tuple-like syntax: `(z) = [4]` :)

Comment: @nightcracker: Indexing with `[0]` isn't equivalent to unpacking, since it doesn't check whether the number of elements in the return value of `plot` matches the number of variables being assigned to.

Comment: Raimond Hettinger about unpacking: https://twitter.com/#!/raymondh/status/190568767158358017

Comment: @ovgolovin: `(z) = [4]` sets `z` to the list `[4]`.

Comment: But you can do `(z,) = [4]`, so that `z` is set to the number `4`

Answer (score 0):

case1:

```
a=1,
type(a)
tuple
```

case2:

```
a=1
type(a)
int
```