# heatmap simple customized binary legend

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

I have this dataframe with `True` and `False` values with a heatmap plot:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
from matplotlib.colors import LinearSegmentedColormap

df = pd.DataFrame({'A': {1: False,  2: False,  3: False,  4: True,  5: True,  6: True,  7: False,  8: False},
 'B': {1: False,  2: False,  3: True,  4: True,  5: False,  6: True,  7: True,  8: False},
 'C': {1: False,  2: True,  3: False,  4: False,  5: False,  6: False,  7: True,  8: True}})

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(3,3))
cmap = sns.mpl_palette("Set2", 2)
sns.heatmap(data=df, cmap=cmap, cbar=False)
plt.xticks(rotation=90, fontsize=10)
plt.yticks(rotation=0, fontsize=10)
plt.show()
```

[image]

I'm trying to add outside the plot a simple legend where the `red color = True` and the `green color = False`, with labels "missing value" when is red, and "non missing value" when is green. I'm not looking for a continuous legend as its common on heatmaps (that's why `cbar=False`).

I have tried multiple solutions (from other plots also) without success: [how to add a legend](https://moonbooks.org/Articles/How-to-add-a-legend-for-a-scatter-plot-in-matplotlib-/), [legend guide](https://matplotlib.org/1.3.1/users/legend_guide.html), [matplotlib legends not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11983024/matplotlib-legends-not-working), [customizing plot legends](https://jakevdp.github.io/PythonDataScienceHandbook/04.06-customizing-legends.html), among others, but all of them are too far complicated to adapt them to heatmap. I'm looking for something like:

```
plt.legend(values=[1,0], colors=["red", "green"], label_legend=["missing value", "non missing value"])
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a [custom legend](https://matplotlib.org/3.3.1/gallery/text_labels_and_annotations/custom_legends.html) as follows:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.patches import Patch
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'A': {1: False, 2: False, 3: False, 4: True, 5: True, 6: True, 7: False, 8: False},
                   'B': {1: False, 2: False, 3: True, 4: True, 5: False, 6: True, 7: True, 8: False},
                   'C': {1: False, 2: True, 3: False, 4: False, 5: False, 6: False, 7: True, 8: True}})

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(3, 3))
cmap = sns.mpl_palette("Set2", 2)
sns.heatmap(data=df, cmap=cmap, cbar=False)
plt.xticks(rotation=90, fontsize=10)
plt.yticks(rotation=0, fontsize=10)

legend_handles = [Patch(color=cmap[True], label='Missing Value'),  # red
                  Patch(color=cmap[False], label='Non Missing Value')]  # green
plt.legend(handles=legend_handles, ncol=2, bbox_to_anchor=[0.5, 1.02], loc='lower center', fontsize=8, handlelength=.8)
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image: resulting plot]

[`Patch`](https://matplotlib.org/3.3.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.patches.Patch.html) creates a "patch" (2D filled shape) which by default is rectangular and which can be given a color.

`cmap[value]` where value is preferably a number between 0 and 1, gives the corresponding color. Note that 'True' and 'False' get converted to 1 and to 0 when used as numeric value. The code above uses 'True' and 'False' for a better readability when comparing with the dataframe. Also note that the syntax is `cmap(value)` with round brackets for a usual matplotlib colormap (seaborn uses a little different syntax, as it extends on matplotlib functionality).

The [`handles=`](https://matplotlib.org/3.3.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.legend.html) for a legend is a list of graphical elements to be put in the legend. Often they are created automatically by many functions, but you can use your own when something non-standard is needed. If the "handles" already have their own labels, they get used in the legend. With `labels=`, they can be changed.

More information can be found in the linked documentation and for example [this tutorial](https://matplotlib.org/3.3.1/tutorials/intermediate/legend_guide.html).

Comment: it works!, thanks!. Can you explain a little bit the logic? What does the `Patch` function do, and the `True` and `False` values in the `color` argument from `Patch` function? and what does the `handles` argument from `plt.legend()` for example?