# Python graphing issue 2

Tags: python, matplotlib, graphing

Ok heres round 2 thank guys for help with the previous problem, but I am back to where I started unfortunately. All this happened when I tried to add a line to this graph. The incoming data is a list coming from another program. For testing purposes I am having the other program spit out [100,110]. I want 100 for one line and 110 for another. Eventually this will be incoming data from an Arduino that will be live data. I keep getting this error.

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
/Users/Tyler/Desktop/Arduino/Graphing_22.py in on_redraw_timer(self, event)
284             #self.data.extend(self.datagen.next())

285 
--> 286         self.draw_plot()
287 
288     def on_exit(self, event):

/Users/Tyler/Desktop/Arduino/Graphing_22.py in draw_plot(self)
240                    visible=self.cb_xlab.IsChecked())
241 
--> 242         self.plot_data.set_xdata(np.arange(len(self.data[0])))
243         #self.plot_data.set_xdata(np.arange([1,1000])

244         self.plot_data.set_ydata(np.array(self.data[1]))

AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'set_xdata'
```

Here is the code for the incoming data and where the error is occurring.

```
def __init__(self):
    wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, -1, self.title)

    self.datagen = DataGen()
    self.data = self.datagen.next()
    #splitting data at '
    #self.data = [self.datagen.next().split(",")
    self.paused = False

 if self.cb_grid.IsChecked():
        self.axes.grid(True, color='gray')
    else:
        self.axes.grid(False)

    # Using setp here is convenient, because get_xticklabels
    # returns a list over which one needs to explicitly 
    # iterate, and setp already handles this.
    #  
    pylab.setp(self.axes.get_xticklabels(), 
               visible=self.cb_xlab.IsChecked())

    self.plot_data.set_xdata(np.arange(len(self.data[0])))
    #self.plot_data.set_xdata(np.arange([1,1000])
    self.plot_data.set_ydata(np.array(self.data[1]))


    self.canvas.draw()
```

Thanks for the help guys!

Comment: How do you define `self.plot_data`?

Comment: self.plot_data = self.axes.plot(
                                        self.data[0], 
                                        linewidth=1,
                                        color=(1, 1, 0),
                                        )

        #adding a line to the plot
        self.plot_data = self.axes.plot(
                                       self.data[1],
                                       linewidth=1,
                                       color=(1, 2, 0),
                                        )

Comment: Can you make your question title more descriptive? 2

Comment: possible duplicate of [line, = plot(x,sin(x)) what does comma stand for?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10422504/line-plotx-sinx-what-does-comma-stand-for)

Comment: You want me to change my title to match what you just wrote? Sorry I am not quite understanding.

Comment: _everything_ tagged `matplotlib` is a graphing issue.  Please change your title to describe your _actual_ issue.

Comment: The 2 was a joke because you posted two questions in a row with identical titles, except for the 2, so I left you two comments which were identical except for a 2 ;)

Answer (score 0):

Given the code from your comment:

```
self.plot_data = self.axes.plot( self.data[0], linewidth=1, color=(1, 1, 0), )
self.axes.plot( self.data[1], linewidth=1, color=(1, 2, 0), )
```

Your issue lies in the fact that `plot` returns a list of the line objects it produces.  Since you appear to be drawing a single line, just make sure you're looking at the first (and only) element of the list.

Either

```
self.plot_data = self.axes.plot( self.data[0], linewidth=1, color=(1, 1, 0), )[0]
```

or

```
self.plot_data[0].set_xdata(np.arange(len(self.data[0])))
```

Comment: Ok I get what you are saying but I want two lines so my list for example is [100,110] I want one line for 100 and another for 110

Answer (score -1):

It appears the way you define `plot_data` returns a list. Also, I'm not sure `axes.plot(*args, **kwargs)`, when used with one argument, is used for data on either axes. I checked in the documentation and found this:

```
plot(x, y)        # plot x and y using default line style and color
plot(x, y, 'bo')  # plot x and y using blue circle markers
plot(y)           # plot y using x as index array 0..N-1
plot(y, 'r+')     # ditto, but with red plusses
```

Return value is a list of lines that were added. There's the type error right there. Here's the documentation for `set_xdata(x)`:

```
set_xdata(x)
    Set the data np.array for x
    ACCEPTS: 1D array
```

And it's from the class:

```
matplotlib.lines.Line2D(xdata, ydata, linewidth=None, linestyle=None, color=None,
marker=None, markersize=None, markeredgewidth=None, markeredgecolor=None,
markerfacecolor=None, markerfacecoloralt='none', fillstyle='full',
antialiased=None, dash_capstyle=None, solid_capstyle=None, dash_joinstyle=None,  
solid_joinstyle=None, pickradius=5, drawstyle=None, markevery=None, **kwargs)
```

So you might consider declaring something like `self.line = plt.lines.Line2D(self.x_data, self.y_data, linewidth=1, color=(1,1,0) )` where you'll have to use something like:

```
self.x_data = self.axes.plot( self.data[0] )
self.y_data = self.axes.plot( self.data[1] )
```

Hope it helps! I referenced:

[update matplotlib plot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13106164/update-matplotlib-plot)

http://matplotlib.org/api/axes_api.html
http://matplotlib.org/api/artist_api.html#matplotlib.lines.Line2D.set_xdata

Comment: Ok that does help a ton. Now let me ask this, What I want to do is have x axis as time as I do right now and have y axis as my incoming data. So there would be two lines, one reading data from the 0 element of my list and the other reading data from the 1 element of my list.

Comment: Also this almost worked. I dont get any error messages, but it does not plot any lines

Comment: Did you write plt.plot() at the end?

Comment: To be honest I wouldnt even know where to put that in the program

Comment: At the end (bottom), friend :).

Comment: Ok tried that, but I still cant get this thing to work. No errors, but also no lines

Comment: Ya what is the best way to send it to you? It is rather long

Comment: Can you put it on Github?