# What does this line do in python plot

Tags: python

```
        plt.plot(red, redforcemean, label='all')
        line, = plt.plot(red, redforcemean, label='11')
```

I have never seen syntax with comma after the word "line," what does this kind of assignment mean?

Comment: can you write full code ?

Comment: read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10422504/line-plotx-sinx-what-does-comma-stand-for) it answers your question.

essential, plt.ploy returns a tuple with only one entry, which gets unpacked into your var.

Comment: Have you ever seen an expression like `var1, var2 = something`? It's the same, except with just one variable.